# Java compare values, best way

Tags: java, performance, methods, switch-statement, comparison

I has a method like this

```
private boolean validGrade(final StringBuilder grade) {
   boolean isValid = false;
   String semester = "semester"; 

   if ((grade.toString().contains("2o") && grade.toString().contains(semester))
                    || (grade.toString().contains("4o") && grade.toString().contains(semester))
                    || (grade.toString().contains("6o") && grade.toString().contains(semester))
                    || (grade.toString().contains("8o") && grade.toString().contains(semester))) {
    isValid = true;
            }
    }
```

And I want to replace it witn something like this:

```
private boolean doValidGradoAntComp(final StringBuilder grade) {
        boolean isValid = false;

        switch (grade.toString()) {
        case "2o semester":
            isValid = true;
            break;
        case "4o semester":
            isValid = true;
            break;
        case "6o semester":
            isValid = true;
            break;
        case "8o semester":
            isValid = true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        return isValid;
    }
```

**And my doubt is:**
which one is better?
Both works in the same way?

Comment: do you think both of the approaches are same? `contains` is different and switch case is different

Comment: I would suggest setting the values outside of the conditional (in some separate Boolean variable. For example, `Boolean bool = grade.toString().contains(semester);`

Comment: Well, I'd say the second option is more readable and thus less easy to get wrong. Additionally it doesn't needlessly call `grade.toString()` multiple times. However, the first variant allows more variants than the second, i.e. `"something semester whatever 2o"` would match `contains("2o")` and `contains("semester")` as well.

Comment: If all the allowed variants look like in your switch above you could also do it in one line: `boolean isValid = grade.toString().matches("[2468]o semester");`

Comment: How about using `static Set<String> sets`, which contains ("2o", "4o", "8o"...). Then using `sets.contains` to do the judgement process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not iterate over the possibilities?

```
private boolean validGrade(final StringBuilder grade) {
    String gradeString = grade.toString();
    return List.of("2o", "4o", "6o", "8o")
        .stream()
        .map(x -> x + " semester")
        .collect(Collectors.toSet())
        .contains(gradeString);
}
```

Alternatively, if you're not looking for exact matches, do:

```
private boolean validGrade(final StringBuilder grade) {
    String gradeString = grade.toString();
    return gradeString.contains("semester") && List.of("2o", "4o", "6o", "8o")
        .stream()
        .anyMatch(gradeString::contains);
}
```

Finally, if your set of matches is inflexible (will always be `"2o", "4o", "6o", "8o"`), then you can just use a regular expression:

```
private boolean validGrade(final StringBuilder grade) {
    return grade.toString().matches("[2468]o semester"); //exact match
//  return grade.toString().matches("[2468]o.*semester|semester.*[2468]o"); //loose match
//  return grade.toString().matches(".*([2468]o.*semester|semester.*[2468]o).*"); //equivalent to contains
}
```

Comment: I'd expand the regex to `.*(the current regex).*` to actually provide a loose match because `String.matches()` only returns true if the _entire_ string matches. That way the regex would more closely match the `contains(...)` logic of the 1st method. :)

Comment: @Thomas In fact, I considered that. Wasn't sure if it was worth it to edit the answer after so long, but it's definitely a good point worth keeping in the comments. In any case, it's there now.

Answer (score 2):

No both the approaches are different, In the first approach you are using `contains` to check two string existed in `grade` (For example `2o` and `semester` in `grade`). But in the second approche you are checking `grade` is equal to `2o semester`. I prefer collecting all those to list and use `anyMatch`

```
List<String> list = List.of("2o","4o","6o","8o");

if(list.stream().anyMatch(val->grade.contains(val) && grade.contains(semester))) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Both serve the same purpose, but each has its differences and weaknesses and strengths.

**If / else**

- Writing and reading difficulty (code is difficult to write because you need to include multivalued checks in one statement)
- Your decision to choose is whether your code will be executed or not.
- As with the switch, you can create a `default` statement if its value is not true (else).

**Switch**

- Easy to write and read code.
- You will always enter the switch block, if there is no case that matches the value you enter it will default.
- You can only use `char` or `int` in cases.
- You only have one condition, unlike if / else you can have several types of conditions.

**Conclusion:**

In performance issues the switch is usually faster but the differences are minimal.

If you have few cases to check I would use `if/else`, but in your case the code you showed is recommended to use the `switch case` for the number of checks that you do it in one block of code only.

Answer (score 1):

Regex may be slower than if-else or switch. But in your case I would put more value on readability and use regex.

```
private boolean validGrade(final StringBuilder grade) {
    return grade.toString().matches("(2o|4o|6o|8o) semester");
}
```